# How to throw error if Runtime.getRuntime().exec fail

Tags: java

i try following:

```
package ro.gd.ex;

/**
 * Created by roroco on 11/17/14.
 */
public class Ex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo -n $(date)|xclip --selection clipboard");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

if i run this cmd in terminal, it will raise

```
roroco@roroco ~/Dropbox/jvs/ro-gd $ echo -n $(date)|xclip --selection clipboard
xclip: --selection: No such file or directory
roroco@roroco ~/Dropbox/jvs/ro-gd $ echo $?
1
```

but in java, it raise nothing, **my question is** how to make this cmd throw error. i found it's exit status is 1.

my os:

```
roroco@roroco ~/Dropbox/jvs/ro-gd $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 17 Qiana
Release:    17
Codename:   qiana
```

Comment: `process.waitFor()` which will return the error level of the command, then simply create a new `Exception` (probably an `IOException`)...You might also consider using `ProcessBuilder` over `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Honestly, didn't want to type that much :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer no, i didn't fix my question, the key point is when i run echo $? in terminal, it's -1 but in int exitCode = process.waitFor();, exitCode is 0, why?

Comment: I'm not convinced that `1` is the exit code (or at least I don't know enough about the command)

Answer (score 2):

`process.waitFor()` which will return the error level of the command, then simply create a new `Exception` (probably an `IOException`)...

```
public class Ex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo -n $(date)|xclip --selection clipboard");
            int exitCode = process.waitFor();
            if (exitCode != 0) {
                throw new IOException("Command exited with " + exitCode);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You might also consider using `ProcessBuilder` over `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
                        "echo",
                        "-n",
                        "$(date)|xclip",
                        "--selection",
                        "clipboard"
        );
        pb.redirectError();
        pb.inheritIO();
        Process process = pb.start();
        // Really should be reading the Process's InputStream
        int exitCode = process.waitFor();
        if (exitCode != 0) {
            throw new IOException("Command exited with " + exitCode);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: no, i didn't fix my question, the key point is when i run `echo $?` in terminal, it's -1 but in `int exitCode = process.waitFor();`, exitCode is 0, why?

Comment: What OS? It prints `0` for me (CLI)

Comment: Also, you need to go clarify your question

Answer (score 1):

How to throw error if Runtime.getRuntime().exec fail

process.waitFor();, exitCode is 0, why?
When:
0=Exit normal.
1=Exit with Error.

the exit value of the subprocess represented by this Process object. By convention, the value 0 indicates normal termination and 1 bad termination..

### some code be like this:

Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Seguridad.bat");

```
        int exitCode = p.waitFor();
        if (exitCode != 0) {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Error Execute when exitCode=1");
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"fine Execute when exitCode=0");

        }
```